# Cannot get Leiningen commands to work with figwheel

Tags: clojure, leiningen, figwheel

After following the instruction set on https://leiningen.org/ to install Leiningen, I have managed to download the batch file and save it within a folder located in: C:\Users\Dylan\Bin\Lein.bat.

[image]

I then ran `lein.bat self-install` in CMD, which created the folder `.lein`:

[image]

At this point the Leiningen is added. I am then able to create a new project called tictactoe using the command `lein new figwheel tictactoe -- --reagent` in CMD and it creates the folder fine. However, the problem arises when I try to compile the tictactoe project, see below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I issue the `lein new figwheel tictactoe -- --reagent` command, it says

```
Generating fresh 'lein new' figwheel project.

Change into your 'tictactoe' directory

Install npm dependencies via 'npm install'
Then run 'lein figwheel'
```

Did you do the `npm install`?

Comment: Hello, yeah i didn't run the npm install first before saying lein figwheel.Thanks for the input :D